# Android Application Crashes on Launch using Google Login

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, google-play-services

Basically, I have an app that logs in with Facebook perfectly, but for my app to functions as i want, it also needs to log into google.
So to start off, I need my app to allow me to log in to google / google + using this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

However as soon as I debug my program it crashes on launch, with no Logcat feedback to let me know where, both in run and debug mode.
The program crashes when I uncomment the following lines of code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

These are the functions for addConnectionCallbacks and connection failed

```
  @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }


}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Get user's information
   // getProfileInformation();

    // Update the UI after signin
    updateUI(true);

}
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    else{
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);// for facebook only
    }

}
```

It's really stumping me at the moment, and i can't continue my development until I get google working.
I have added these into my manifest also:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<application
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

I have also put in the correct appnumber form the development console and the SHA1 code from the keytool generator. I have also enabled the google play API in the console.

I can't think what else it could be if i'm honest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There would be some logs for sure. Please provide logs otherwise it is very difficult to help here.

Comment: Honestly, the logcat remains empty. I really don't know why.

Comment: Can you run logcat on the command line? Do  `logcat | grep YourPackageName`

Comment: Ill try it tonight and post any results.

Comment: Try to follow these step [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/samples/quickstart-android) and get the code [here](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android).

Comment: .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null) it was this line. Can't have an objct reference of null

Comment: did you make sure your activity does not use android:noHistory="true"?

Comment: Hi teh.fonsi .... I am facing same issue. Yes used no history. What happen if i use noHistory true